# CSS Find sibling of a parent using css class and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

### DEMO

How to update `B` text when `C` is clicked?

**HTML**

```
<div class="A">
    <div><span class="B">TEXT</span></div>
    <div>
        <div id="C" onclick="tx(this.id);">CLICK ME</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function tx (e){
    $('#' + e).closest('.A').children('.B').text('SUCCESS');
}
```

I cant understand why the above jquery does not work.

It should find nearest parent then child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery anyway, assign your event handlers that way instead of using "onclick" attributes:

```
$("body").on("click", "#C", function() {
    $(this).closest('.A').find('.B').text('SUCCESS');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="A">
    <div><span class="B">TEXT</span></div>
    <div>
        <div id="C">CLICK ME</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that as set up, your fiddle won't work because the "tx" function is configured (via jsfiddle settings) to be inside a "load" handler, and is therefore not a global symbol.

[Fixed fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/ts92mzko/)

Answer (score 1):

You have many parents, so this can get a little confusing.  Make sure you use `.children()` twice.

```js
function tx(e) {
  $('#' + e).parents('.A').children().children('.B').text('SUCCESS');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
  <div><span class="B">TEXT</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="C" onclick="tx(this.id);">CLICK ME</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `.closest()` really is the better choice here, because it is guaranteed to return a jQuery object with either zero or one members.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are calling the click event inline? I would rather do all the events on DOM ready and then simply do something like:  http://jsfiddle.net/t668p52p/3/

```
$('#C').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.A').find('.B').text('SUCCESS');
});
```

Comment: Yes it is just a mistake in my fiddle. fixed now.